# Как установить одну версию nodejs для root и user

Tags: linux, node.js, nvm

При выполнении команды

```
which node
```

на правах юзера выдает

```
/usr/bin/node
```

А при использовании той же команды на root правах

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin/node
```

Я первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь и у меня нет большого опыта в решении подобных моментов. Буду рада помощи.